# Flexbox Nav Dropdown Not Under Container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use a flexbox nav menu with dropdowns for some menus. For some reason, on hover, the dropdown lists are showing up to the right of the container I am hovering on. I would like for them to show below, like a normal nav menu.

Here is a codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbmaBY

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul class="nav-flex">
    <li class="nav-brand-flex">
      <a href=""><img src="img.png" \></a>
    </li>
       <li class="nav-link-flex nav-flex-dropdown">
       <a href="">Dropdown 1</a>
       <div>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link-flex nav-flex-dropdown">
       <a href="">Dropdown 2</a>
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link-flex">
      <a href="">Regular 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link-flex">
      <a href="">Regular 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link-flex">
      <a href="">Regular 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Sass:

```
.nav-flex {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #58575f;

    li {
        justify-content: center;

        a {
            align-self: center;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            letter-spacing: .4px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 760px) {
        padding-top: 0;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }
}

.nav-link-flex {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 12.5px;
    position: relative;

    @media (max-width: 760px) {
        width: 90%;
        background-color: #494949;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: white;

        a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;

            &+ div {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }

    a {

        &+ div {
            border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            display: none;
            font-size: 1rem;
            position: absolute;
            width: 195px;
        }
    }
}

.nav-brand-flex {
    margin-right: auto; 
    display: flex;  
    padding: 5px 0;    

    a {
        display: flex;
        img {

            height: 35px;
            align-self: center;
        } 
    }

    @media (max-width: 760px) {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #494949;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I cannot figure out why they are going to the right instead of below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the default value of flex-direction is `flex-direction: row`. You want to override this, by adding `flex-direction: column;` to `.nav-link-flex`. So, it should be:

`.nav-link-flex {
        display: flex;
        padding: 0 12.5px;
        position: relative;
        flex-direction: column; // <-- add this line in your scss
    ...`

By way of example I've added this in to [a fork of your pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGwLQm).